# Auto-scaling with a custom, private AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up an auto scaling profile to scale my own cloud automatically. I have created a private AMI image which I'd like to use as the image launched when creating new servers in this configuration. I'm using the auto-scaling command-line controls to create the profile and I can't seem to get it working:

```
$ as-create-launch-config MyServerConfig --image-id "ami-12345678" --instance-type m2.4xlarge --monitoring-disabled
as-create-launch-config: Malformed input-AMI ami-12345678 is invalid: The AMI ID 'ami-12345678' does not exist
```

I've verified that the AMI id that I'm using does, in fact, exist in my EC2/Images/AMIs part of the EC2 console. What am I doing wrong here? I need to have the images be private due to the company's privacy requirements, but I do need to set up auto-scaling to get things going for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your AMI and the AutoScaling group are in the same region and that you are correctly specifying that region in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to wrong region. by default it looks into us-east-1 enpoint. You can specify the region like following -

as-create-launch-config your_autoscale_config --region us-west-2 --image-id "your_image_id" --instance-type m1.small

To get the list of region names go to this url

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#as_region